# Looking for `flatten :: Event [a] -> Event a` in Reactive Banana

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

I'm looking for something like `flatten :: Event [a] -> Event a` (swap `[]` with `Foldable f => f` if you want) which would generate a separate event for each `a` in an `Event`'s list, like [`split` in an old version of `sodium`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium-0.11.0.3/docs/FRP-Sodium.html#v:split).

I suspect that this is somehow possible with `switchE`, but then I'd need a function of type `[a] -> Event a`.

I could possibly craft that myself with `newEvent`, but is there a function built-in to `reactive-banana`?

**Edit**:

Actually, I'm not so sure I can implement that with `newEvent` after all.

```
flatten :: Foldable f => f a -> Banana.MomentIO (Banana.Event a)
flatten xs = do
  (event, fire) <- Banana.newEvent
  liftIO $ forkIO $ mapM_ fire xs
  return event
```

Will `fire` block until there are subscribers or will it just return immediately if there aren't any?

**Edit 2**:

Looking at the [implementation of `newAddHandler`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.0/docs/src/Control-Event-Handler.html#newAddHandler) my implementation above won't work, because all events are possibly fired before any handlers can register.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be impossible. According to [the notes in Heinrich Apfelmus's blog](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2015/08/29-frp-banana-api-redesign.html), `Event` doesn't support simultaneous occurrences. This is a relatively recent change; the post is dated August last year and v1.0 was released in October. It certainly wasn't the case when I originally learned Reactive Banana a few years ago.

But `Event [a]` seems like a reasonable way to represent a set of coincidental events in the first place. Why do you need to flatten it?

Comment: I want to perform an `IO` action for each one of those `a`s (fetch/clone git repositories) and then execute downstream code after each one (e.g. build and benchmark the project). I'd prefer to do it in a 'depth-first' (running corresponing fetch and build consecutive) rather than 'breadth-first' manner (running all fetches, then running all builds). There are also other event sources which produce single `a`s, but I could wrap that in singleton lists of course.

Comment: Actually, I think doing `IO` is the only thing where it matters semantically.

Comment: I think `fmap (traverse (clone >=> build)) :: Event [Project] -> Event (IO ())` would do that, no?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd rather separate `clone` and `build` into their own events/arrows, because `build` can be also triggered by other events. But thanks for the suggestions, I'll go try something.

Comment: Just make `clone` and `build` into separate functions , as I suggested above, and `fmap (traverse build)` over the other events that could trigger a build

Comment: I'll run with that! Although that leaves me a little puzzled wrt. how I should structure my application. Originally I thought I could just have many modules exporting `Event a -> MomentIO (Event b)` arrows hiding IO and state in a well-behaved way. Now I have to 'break' that rule with `build`, although it seems OK because it is a sink in the network anyway.

Comment: *Event doesn't support simultaneous occurrences.* This is also the case for more recent versions of sodium, by the way.

Comment: @Sebastian That's not how I'd structure the code. Confine your use of the `Reactive.Banana.Frameworks` module to the entry point of your application, which should just consist of calls to `fromAddHandler` (to bind inputs) and `reactimate` (to bind outputs). Keeping `MomentIO` out of your library modules promotes composability.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I got the network to do what I want now.